# Apple rejected my app due to use of non public api UIRotatingAlertController, WKActionSheet

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

> Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements

Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change. Specifically:

OS_dispatch_group, _UIRotatingAlertController, WKActionSheet

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.

> Blockquote

I have resolved two out of them which I able to find out in my code this are "prefs:root" and "OS_dispatch_group" but other two are not detecting in code. here I am using command `grep -R '_UIRotatingAlertController' *`. Please suggest if need run any other commands for nm tool or otool.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party libraries? The remaining two private APIs might be used by the frameworks you use.

Comment: Yes i am using tired party libraries but how can i detect this non public api is in which library or framework

Comment: You can check the public interfaces of these frameworks. But you should also research if other people had these problems with the frameworks you are using, this method might turn out to be easier than looking for the private API usage by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blockquote
>   These two selectors are both present in the [JSQMessagesViewController initialize]-> JSQInstallWorkaroundForSheetPresentationIssue26295020() method and are directly obfuscating their use to avoid static detection (https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/f52e83bdb4d5c19ecfd5b6e54cdb9f2efa66cfcf/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m). It would be appropriate to remove the library entirely before resubmitting for review.

This is a reply from apple as this API is used with some trick so i have unable to observe the problem but apple easily observe with their tools.